# Configure Wireshark to capture preformatted data from pseudo-device

Tags: linux, wireshark, packet

So, for a research project, I'm trying to use the HONE project on github, which creates during its module installation two pseudo-devices in the /dev folder.  These are called hone and honet, the former containing the information it is programmed to receive in pcapng format, and the latter a human-readable text interpretation.

As it stands, I can't find a way to reliably and continuously get information from the hone device.  I could use `cat`, but it runs the risk of cutting off writing mid-packet.  HONE also comes with a program for logging the information to a file, called `honelogd`, but still, I need to run my software continuously.

Is it possible to configure Wireshark to accept this pseudo-device as a capture interface?

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is usually a poor choice for things that must run continuously.  dumpcap, part of the wireshark suite, is a better choice.  You should be able to specify the hone device with -i hone (or -i /dev/hone) to dumpcap.  Alternatively, dumpcap can read from a named pipe, which could read from the device.  See: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'd tried the former,  which didn't work, but given the chance, I'll attempt the named pipe route.

Comment: Okay, finally checked the man page, and even though it told me the problem, I tried it just to be thorough.  I made a named pipe and read info from /dev/hone into it, then used the pipe to capture with dumpcap.  Apparently, reading from a named pipe does not support pcap-ng format.  It throws an 'unrecognized libpcap format' error and exits.  Unless I can have something capture pcapng, there is no point to it, as the extra information is essential to my project.